# How to prevent lost session value in laravel 5.2 when redirect from any controller to another controller?

Tags: laravel, session

I am trying to make login system in laravel 5.2 I store session data using put method. 
this is my login controller where I store session data in displayHome() function

```
 <?php
        namespace App\Http\Controllers;
        use Illuminate\Http\Request;
        use App\Http\Requests;
        use App\app_users;
        use Redirect;
        use Session;
        use Crypt;
        class login extends Controller
        {


        function displayHome(){
          $request->session()->put('session_login',array('email'=>'someone@gmail.com','username'=>$'someone'));
         //print_r(session('session_login')); die();
         //`data session successfully stored `
        }
        }
```

I already `printr()` session value. Everything work fine and session stored.
But session lost Its value when I am redirecting to another controller this is how I redirecting to another controller

```
return Redirect::to('members');
```

My route members look like

```
 Route::group(['module' => 'Members', 'middleware' => ['web'], 'namespace' => 'App\Modules\Members\Controllers'], function() {
        Route::get('members','MembersController@index');
});
```

MembersController look like

```
namespace App\Modules\Members\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
Use Redirect;
use Session;
class MembersController extends Controller
{
function index(){
//data session is empty 
print_r(session()->get('session_login')); die();
}
}
```

I try to get session data inside index fuction() and the result empty. please give me right solution to solve that?

Comment: (1) what is the session storage? (2) does the laravel cookie there?

Comment: @Bagus Tesa 21 I am using file driver. this is user guide about session from 
https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/session

Comment: [could you check on browser console](https://www.wikihow.com/View-Cookies) for the laravel cookie (`laravel_session`)? because to tie up a user with a session, a cookie is needed. if the cookie somehow lost, every request may be rendered as a new session.

Comment: have you tried the laravel Default [Auth](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/authentication) System?

Comment: @Sithira,this link is not exists anymore https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/authentication]

Comment: @Alimin my bad here you go.... https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/authentication

Comment: @Sithira someday we need to make own session manipulation depend on our case I think I have to solve my problem. so let assume this is another case beside laravel authentification. for example using session in shoping cart

Comment: @Alimin yes, you can... but the Default auth does all the encryption that it needs before it saves. But in your case, you would have to do them manually, so I'd suggest taking a look into laravel default auth implementation, so you can have a good idea about how laravel do things and implement it to your own.

Comment: yes I think so, may be I do Ilegal session access in laravel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the `flash` method to retain session data between requests:

```
$request->session()->flash('session_login', $data);
```

And then `reflash()` and `keep` are available for even more requests:

```
$request->session()->reflash();

$request->session()->keep(['session_login']);
```

> Sometimes you may wish to store items in the session only for the next request. You may do so using the flash method.
>
> If you need to keep your flash data around for even more requests, you may use the reflash method, which will keep all of the flash data around for an additional request. If you only need to keep specific flash data around, you may use the keep method.

[Flash Session Data](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/session#flash-data)

**update**

Ensure you have `\Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class` added to the `web` middleware group in your `Kernel.php`.

Comment: I try your solution. and now I get error message
RuntimeException in Request.php line 870:
Session store not set on request.

Comment: Please make sure the `\Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class` is enabled in your kernel.

Comment: which file is this  \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class  I already open Kernel.php but not find anything

Comment: It's in the web middleware group. Here's the default: https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/master/app/Http/Kernel.php

Comment: yes I solve my problem 
I change this at Kernel.php
I am updating 
protected $middleware = [
        \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\CheckForMaintenanceMode::class,
    ];

to be
protected $middleware = [
 \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\CheckForMaintenanceMode::class,
    \App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
    \Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse::class,
    \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
    \Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
    \App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class
}

Comment: @ DigitalDrifter this is the correct answer I think. "It's in the web middleware group. Here's the default:" how to mark it? :D

Comment: I'll add it to the answer. Thank!